# Stuck with array

Tags: python, arrays

Assume you have a Python list (array) a of length 10, of which the last 3 cells contain None, the others have some other content.

Doesn't the following code copy the content of 5th cell of a to all cells after it up to the end of the array a and replace the content of the 5th cell of a by '20' or am i wrong?

```
for in in range (len(a)-1, 4, -1):
    a[i+i] = a[i]
a[4] = 20
```

Comment: You are using the keyword `in` as a looping variable. Else, this code would throw you an IndexError.

Comment: As this code isn't valid Python syntax, it doesn't *do* anything.

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you want to do ?

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, None, None, None]
for i in range (len(a)-1, 4, -1):
    a[i] = a[4]
a[4] = 20
print (a) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to copy the value of `a[6]` to all following indices of your array `a`, you can do this with the following

```
# create the array you mention, some values up to index 6 then three None
a = [f for f in range(0,10)]
a[7] = a[8] = a[9] = None
print(a)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, None, None, None]

# we copy the value of a[6] to the rest
for i in range(6, len(a) -1):
    a[i+1] = a[i]

print(a)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

If, however, you want to replace all values that are `None` in your array by the value `6`, you can do

```
# create the array you mention, some values up to index 6 then three None
a = [f for f in range(0,10)]
a[7] = a[8] = a[9] = None
# replace all None values by 6 and reassign a
a = [6 if v is None else v for v in a]
print(a)
```